# Android draws last visible state after visibility change

Tags: android

I have a custom ViewGroup which is not visible at all times. When the view is not visible I clear all children by calling `removeAllViews()`. The problem is when I change the visibility the old content is being drawn first, before updating to the new content, which results in the screen flashing. I tried calling `destroyDrawingCache()` which didn't help. Is there anything I'm missing here?

As for my custom ViewGroup - the only thing this is doing is overwriting `onMeasure()` and `onLayout()` to lay out the children correctly.

Comment: Instead of removing all the views, why don't you just call setVisibility(GONE); on the ViewGroup or on all the Views?

Comment: No, I need to actually remove the views. The children are dynamically generated views. When I show the ViewGroup again the content is completely different.

Comment: Could you post some code? I tried to recreate the problem with an custom viewgroup, added some imageviews to it, set visibility to invisible/gone, called removeAllViews(), added new views, set visibility to visible ... no problem so far 
(maybe try to invalidate the viewgroup in the activity or call refreshDrawableState)

Comment: The problem was an animation when adding the views, which had fillAfter set to true - this was causing the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the issue! When I was adding the children I had a ScaleAnimation with the fillAfter flag set to true. This was causing the issue. Removing the fillAfter flag resolved the issue.
It was only happening on ICS+ FYI, so probably an issue of hardware acceleration.